# Transfrom.translate vs Matrix4.translate in flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter, flutter-animation

I have some questions about Transform and Matrix4 with animation in flutter, I need your help !

I have been confused of the concept of this for days. As the title, is the Transform.translate same as Matrix4.translate? I read the docs and implementation of these two methods. I found that **Transform.translate** simply change the entry 12, 13, 14 of Matrix4; however, **Matrix4.translate** is more complicated, it even changes the entry 15 of Matrix4. Does it mean they are different?

Originally, I think they are the same thing. But, why these two kinds of code generate different results: [Code1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mFsvB_dxuKvcn2KOUSrI_CN6DVE4HmoD/view?usp=sharing) [Code2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lBfp165LBDGyOHsOpNmEHP-kQnIznhtS/view?usp=sharing)

My last question is that in the [code3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16nRkzPr9cZyHdPn6C9t5mgCBOaEIsxbp/view?usp=sharing), I tried to change the order of setEntry and rotateY methods, and I got different result on simulator. Why, I think they should be the same.

I think I am misunderstand the much concept about them, any advice is appreciated !!!

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Post text as text.

Comment: Your `index_of_one` check is definitely slowing everything down, as well as making the code more complicated.  Also you are guaranteed `n <= 100,000`, so you shouldn't be using `unsigned long long` for array indexes, use `unsigned int` instead.  It also isn't clear to me why you can break out of your inner loop early.

Comment: Turksarama, thank for your comment. But if I find 1 I can directly add up to tuple counts. Is there an efficient way that I need not to check the index of one ? By the way, after I find the sequence that gcd is one, I can make sure that all no matter which new number into sequence, the gcd of sequence is still one, so I break the inner loop !